# Counting inversions in a vector using mergesort c++

Tags: c++, vector, mergesort, inversion

The algorithm is returning an off by one error for some of the inputs I send to it. I wrote the merge_sort and inversion_count with array first; which gave back the right number of inversions. Once I transitioned to vectors I receive off by one for the following input: 
2 4 1 3 5

A fresh pair of eyes would be appreciated.

```
vector<int> a;
object o;

length = a.size();
inv = o.count_inversion(a, 0, length-1);



int inversion::merge_and_count(vector<int> vector1, int alpha, int omega)
{
    int inversion = 0;
    int mid = (alpha + omega) / 2;
    int i = alpha;
    int j = mid + 1;
    int lastITR = 0;
    vector<int> final(omega - alpha + 1);


while (i <= mid && j <= omega) {
    if (vector1[i] <= vector1[j])
    {
            final[lastITR++] = vector1[i++];
    }
    else
    {
            final[lastITR++] = vector1[j++];
            inversion += mid - i + 1;
    }
}

while (i <= mid)
    {
    {
    final[lastITR++] = vector1[i++];
    }

    while (j <= omega)
    {
    final[lastITR++] = vector1[j++];
    }

    for (int k=0 ; k < omega-alpha+1; k++)
    {
    vector1[k+alpha] = final[k];
    }

return inversion;
}


int inversion::count_inversion(vector<int> vector1, int a, int b)
{
int x, y, z, mid;

if (a >= b)
    {
            return 0;
    }

mid = (a+b)/2;

x = count_inversion(vector1, a, mid);
y = count_inversion(vector1, mid+1, b);
z = merge_and_count(vector1, a, b);

return x + y + z;
}
```

Comment: Man, thats a lot of vector copies. unrelated, but did you think about doing this with *iterators* ? And you know you're passing those by value, and as such, that last `vector1[]` assignment loop in merge_and_count does nothing, right?

Comment: Please post a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/). It should be possbile for a reader of your post to copy and paste your code, compile it and run it without modifying it. What is `inversion` in `inversion::merge_and_count`? A namespace?

Comment: What output did you get and what output do you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one thing likely causing your issue is below (note: I have no idea what you're trying to do, but I don't think it honestly matters):

```
int inversion::merge_and_count(vector<int> vector1, int alpha, int omega)
// note: pass by *value*, not reference ------^
```

Clearly you intend to actually modify this vector for the caller, because at the end of your routine:

```
for (int k=0 ; k < omega-alpha+1; k++)
{
    vector1[k+alpha] = final[k];
}
```

Essentially, you're building a merged `final`, then copying it into a vector that is about to be destroyed. The caller-side `vector<int>` is untouched when this is done, staying the same as it was prior.

Fix this by using a reference:

```
int inversion::merge_and_count(vector<int>& vector1, int alpha, int omega)
// note: reference -----------------------^
```

There are some potential problems, but that is likely the one that is giving you grief. Passing by-value into `count_inversion` should be ok, since it isn't clear you want to modify the caller-vector there, and if this is only counting inversions, you likely don't want to. But `merge_and_count` needs to use a reference.

Note: Once you learn iterators you'll happily use them for modeling something like this. It makes the code not only cleaner, but automagically allows its use on any sequence container supporting the proper iterator type.

Comment: It actually took modifying both function declarations to get the correct output. I thank you for the prompt response and of course solving the problem.

Comment: @user2869622 You're right. I just realized it (`count_inversion`) was the root of the recursion. Nice catch. And glad it helped.